# R: Chi-squared doesn't detect (even big) differences in simulated, ordinal data

Tags: r, ordinal

While trying to do give a seminar on how to analyse ordinal data (and why metric tests, such as the t-test are bad to use in this case), I have tried to do chi-squared tests on simulated data in R.

No matter how big I make the differences, however, I cannot detect this difference with:

```
chisq.test(data,data2)
```

When running a large number of simulations, only ~ 5 percent of the p-values are below 0.05 indicating there is no true difference.

[image]

... Which confuses me, as I know the difference is there.

Is there anything wrong with my code? https://pastebin.com/NtbJGpez

All input is more than appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your code.  I think the problem is the hypothesis.  The null hypothesis for the chi-square test is that the two samples are independent. Rejection of the hypothesis suggests that there is evidence pointing toward an association.  As it turns out, your data sets _are_ independent.  That means you're simulating under the conditions of the null hypothesis, not the alternative. What you  need is a process to simulate dependent ordinal data.

Comment: Hello Benjamin and thanks for you answer. After looking into it again, I see that you are right. The code does what I ask it to.

What I should do instead is something like this:
'chisq.test(c(rep(1,simn),rep(2,simn)),c(data,data2))'

After doing that, the p-values matches more closely the differences in my simulations.